# Has FIQ mode its own stack?

Tags: assembly, arm

I am a little bit confused about banked registers in *FIQ* mode. *FIQ* mode has banked SP register. Does it means that *FIQ* mode has its own stack?

Comment: yes, if you look at the chart it shows the different banked registers and the ones that have their own sp mean they have their own stack

Comment: @old_timer Would you write that as answer?

Comment: Does ARMv7A and earlier automatically push values on the stack like ARMv7M does? If not, you might not need a stack in FIQ mode if your handler is simple enough.

Answer (score 2):

armv4 to armv6 has banked stack pointers as the arm architectural reference manuals show. Which does mean, yes, each of these modes, svc, irq, fiq, ... have their own stacks. You will see the bootstrap code for these parts will bounce through the modes setting up stacks.

This is within ARM's domain, chips are mostly stuff other than the arm, and what is connected to fiq or irq is up to the chip vendor.  I have seen a number of them where everything can trigger the fiq or irq giving the programmer the choice, which leads to if you don't use fiq or don't use the other modes then you don't need to setup those stacks.